# How to use pipx install -r?

Tags: python, arch-linux, pip

I was really wondering how can I use the `pipx install -r requirements.txt` like we do using pip? Is there an alternative to that?
When I was using it, it shows:

```
[xyro@arch terra]$ pipx install -r  requirements.txt
usage: pipx [-h] [--version]
            {install,uninject,inject,upgrade,upgrade-all,uninstall,uninstall-all,reinstall,reinstall-all,list,run,runpip,ensurepath,environment,completions}
            ...
pipx: error: unrecognized arguments: -r
```

Comment: What are you trying to install?